# About cv_wgt_start for CVs with quite different delays

Tags: gekko

We are trying to control tclab with man made big delay. We followed suggestions in [url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66335889/14889996). The
cv_wgt_start worked very well. See [image: pic]. I set CV_wgt_delay as double relay time(fopdt).

But my question is as cv_mgt_start is the global option, how can we deal with two CVS with quite different delays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to have a different delay is to define a custom objective function with a parameter `p` that is a step function where the penalty starts. In this example, there are 10 time steps in the control / prediction horizon. The penalty (5) starts at step 7 for `T1` and step 3 for `T2`.

```py
from gekko import gekko
import numpy as np

p1 = np.zeros(11)
p1[6:] = 5
p1 = m.Param(p1)

p2 = np.zeros(11)
p2[2:] = 5
p2 = m.Param(p2)

m.Minimize(p1*(T1-55)**2)
m.Minimize(p2*(T2-35)**2)
```

Another [option](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmCvType) is to use `m.CV_TYPE=3` as a derivative form of the reference trajectory. This is especially suited for systems with time delay.

Comment: Hi, professior, m.CV)_TYPE=3 works really well.  I do not need cv_wgt_start any more.  Can you explain more about the derivative form of the reference trajectory and why it is suitable for system s with time delay?

Comment: It uses the derivative form versus an absolute form. If there is time delay then it adjusts the MV move plan to be proportionally aggressive in reaching the set point based on how far it is away, not based on a fixed CV time-based target.

Comment: OK. I will investigate the code to see if i can understand better.